# Routing in ASP NET Web API - For different versions of an API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I am reading about `Attribute Routing in Web API 2` from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

The article says,

```
Here are some other patterns that attribute routing makes easy.

API versioning

In this example, “/api/v1/products” would be routed to a different controller than “/api/v2/products”.

/api/v1/products
/api/v2/products
```

How come?

EDIT: I would do this in ***Normal Routing:***

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v2/products",
            defaults: new { controller = V2_Products }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/products",
            defaults: new { controller = V1_Products }
        );
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain me how to do this in `Attribute Routing` way ? And how come using `Attribute routing` is easier and convenient for this example (according to the article) ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question directly, but I really liked this blog post on the topic because it goes deeper into various approaches to versioning an API: https://www.troyhunt.com/your-api-versioning-is-wrong-which-is/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to implement versionning with attribute routing ; A really basic way is to use [RoutePrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeprefixattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute for each version of your ApiController

```
[RoutePrefix("v1")]
public class V1_ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("products")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "v1-product1", "v1-product2" };
    }
     //....
}


[RoutePrefix("v2")]
public class V2_ProductsController : ApiController
{
     [Route("products")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "v2-product1", "v2-product2" };
    }
    //....
}
```

`/v1/products` goes to the first version of `/v2/products` goes to the second one.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by overriding **DefaultHttpControllerSelector**

there you override method to selectcontroller

```
public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = null;
                IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> controllers = GetControllerMapping();

                IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();

                if (routeData == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                }

                object apiVersion;
                if (!routeData.Values.TryGetValue("Version", out apiVersion))
                {
                    apiVersion = "1";
                }


                object controllerName;
                if (!routeData.Values.TryGetValue("controller", out controllerName))
                {
                    controllerName = string.Empty;
                }
                if (controllerName == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                }

                string newControllerName = String.Concat(controllerName.ToString(), "V", apiVersion);

                if (controllers.TryGetValue(newControllerName, out controllerDescriptor))
                {
                    return controllerDescriptor;
                }
                if (controllers.TryGetValue(controllerName.ToString(), out controllerDescriptor))
                {
                    return controllerDescriptor;
                }
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            }
```

Then you are adding routes webapiconfig

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and register controller selector in webapiconfig

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new ApiVersioningSelector(config));
```

So from now if you name controller ProductsV1Controller it will reffer /api/v1/products. Also please note that my example also support routes without version so if v1 is not found it will try to check if ProductsController exists

PS. Code is update one bug was there :(

Comment: Volodymyr Bilyachat answer's bug is this line string newControllerName = String.Concat(controllerName.ToString(), "V", apiVersion); fix: string newControllerName = String.Format("Controllers.{0}{1}", controllerName.ToString(), apiVersion);

Comment: I have an issue with this method when i define custom route for each api metho. i.e. I would like to define Route for my method [Route("Product")]. Any idea on how can we define custom route along with this overriding?

Comment: So what you want to do if route is there?

Comment: Let's say i have two diff post method with same parameter, i have to define custom route for each. But if define route, this overriding stops working. It says, method not allowed.

Comment: You need to check if action has route then use base class to handle that

Comment: do you mean we need to hard code route on base class?

Comment: No i mean that what you can do its check if your Action method has attribute route and then use base class from HttpControllerSelector to return

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way is configuring your route as api/{folder}/{controller}/{action} where in to folder you can give name as V1 or V2.

A good way can be implementing your own Controller selector. You can use [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/) for more information.

The interface that Web API uses to select a controller is `IHttpControllerSelector`. The important method on this interface is SelectController, which selects a controller for a given HttpRequestMessage.

Comment: I think the working link is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/ now.